# Word counter doesn't work for large files and have some problems

Tags: c++, counter

I must read and count a specific column (in my file its 6th column) in .csv file but ı couldn't and also what ı wrote works for small files, it reads every word in a file and it prints but when it comes to big files (in my Project ı have a .csv file which contains 1 million tweets) console window appears and my CPU goes to 35-40 (sometimes higher) but it doesn't prints the data.I waited like 1 hour but then ı closed it because ı should make this work around 5 minutes.I have some stopwords and ı don't know how to ignore them. I know ı have many questions but ı am new at this

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <chrono>

const int MAX = 1000000;
std::string words[MAX];
int instances[MAX];
int count =0;


void insert(std::string input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        if (input == words[i]) {
            instances[i]++;
            return;
        }
    if (count < MAX) {
        words[count] = input;
        instances[count] = 1;
        count++;
    }

}

int findTop(std::string &word) {
    int topCount = instances[0];
    int topIndex = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<count; i++)
        if (instances[i] > topCount) {
            topCount = instances[i];
            topIndex = i;
        }
    instances[topIndex] = 0;
    word = words[topIndex];
    return topCount;

}

int main() {
    using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    using s = std::chrono::seconds;
    const auto before = clock::now();

    std::string word;
    std::ifstream data("eray.csv");
    while (data >> word)
        insert(word);
    data.close();
    int topCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
        std::cout << word << "    " << findTop(word) << std::endl;
    }
    const auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<s>(clock::now() - before);
    std::cout << "\nTotal Elapsed Time : " << duration.count() << "s" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I assume you are not permitted to use std::map?

Comment: yes ı cant use that and also ı cant use third party libraries

Comment: I think you have to be more specific to exactly what the problem is.

Comment: And be clear with your constraints. For example, if you can use std::vector and the std algorithm library, this would be simpler to solve.

Comment: You're going to have to be much, *much* clearer on what "when ı open a big file it doesnt work" actually *means*. We know it doesn't work (you wouldn't be here if it did). But, what *does* it do? Have you run this in a *debugger* and stepped through the code you're having issues with?

Comment: you are right ı edited the post about my problem

Comment: ***I waited like 1 hour but then ı closed it because ı should make this work around 5 minutes.*** Break into the debugger and see what code it is executing.

Comment: @jrprogrammer *yes ı cant use that* -- Yes, because if you used it, the program will magically write itself.  I hope you see that is sarcasm -- sarcasm directed at the stupidity of such a requirement.

Comment: `int topCount = 0;` in main does not seem to be used.

Comment: It's really not clear where the bug exists.

Comment: Did you try a release build? Perhaps the debug build is too slow. I have seen cases where a debug build in Visual Studio takes 100 times as long as release.